# Does MariaDB have a scableable equivilant of MYSQL/Oracle JSON_TABLE

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I need to un-nest a large array stored as part of a JSON document.

In Oracle and MYSQL I can use JSON_TABLE for this

In SQL Server I can use OPENJSON

In Postgres I can use JSON(B)_array_elements

But I'm hitting a wall in MariaDB....

I've scoured the documentation and can't see how do to do.. I might need to un-nest several thousand rows, and all of the aforementioned database have been able to complete the un-nesting in a scaleable and performant manner....

Here's a very simplified subset of the data

```
{ "data": {
    "EMPLOYEES": [
        [100,   "Steven",   "King",     "SKING",    "515.123.4567",     "2003-06-17T00:00:00",  "AD_PRES",  24000,  null,   null,   90  ],
        [101,   "Neena",    "Kochhar",  "NKOCHHAR", "515.123.4568",     "2005-09-21T00:00:00",  "AD_VP",    17000,  null,   100,    90  ]
    ],
    "DEPARTMENTS": [
        [10,    "Administration",   200,    1700],
        [20,    "Marketing",        201,    1800]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: look https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-json-table-type/

Comment: MySQL does not have very good JSON support, and I would not expect MariaDB to improve much on that.  Check the documentation to see what you can/can't do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I was able to achieve my goal with the JSON support in MySQL 8, which includes JSON_TABLE which does exactly what I need and seems to be OK. My biggest problem with MYSQL is moving large JSON files from the client platform to the database using NODE.js in order to decompose them. Unless I am missing something I have to use LOAD FILE LOCAL PATH for this, which is painfully slow. I don't see anyway to stream a file to a longtext column using the MYSQL node driver

Comment: @HaimEvgi. I've read that link and I don't think that it will meet my needs. If I understand it it relies on being able to stage the file to be processed on the server. I don't see anyway that I can have a node client written using MariasDB Node Driver upload the files that I need to process. I am also not sure that it can process the files I need to look at which basically are a database dump with an array for each table, containing an array for each row. Each table is represented by an object named for the table....

Comment: The data should have been split into rows and columns of tables _before_ inserting.  `JSON` is inappropriate for that kind of data and structure.

Comment: @RickJames - Your _opinion_ has been noted. I am glad you fully understand the scope of the problem I need to solve and my reasons for choosing the approach I have taken from one small snippet of information

Answer (score 1):

As of 10.3.12 MariaDB does not have a JSON_TABLE function

Comment: And the tricky "black magic" solution is a large technical debt you will have to pay sometime